# Cannot compile C++ files with boost and odeint

Tags: odeint

I installed boost using `brew install boost` in order to use odeint library (the [odeint webpage](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/numeric/odeint/doc/html/boost_numeric_odeint/getting_started/usage__compilation__headers.html) says : odeint is a header-only library, no linking against pre-compiled code is required).

I am on Mac Yosemite 10.10.5 . Now when I cd to /usr/local/include, I can see boost directory there. Inside boost (`/usr/local/include/boost`) there are all the header files I needed for my project, along with the numeric/odeint directories needed for my specific purposes. At the same time, when I cd to `usr\local\lib`, I can see a lot of `libboost_*` `.dylib` and `.a` files.

However, when I try to compile a c++ file that I temporarily save in ~/Downloads (the first header is `#include <boost/array.hpp>`), I got the error `fatal error: 'boost/array.hpp' file not found`.

I am inexperienced in programming, and I really appreciate your help! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use the following include statements and let us know if it works.

```
#include <boost/numeric/odeint.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/matrix.hpp>
```

If not, some additional info is needed. What is your BOOST version, what is the structure of the /usr/local/include/boost directory, how about including other (non-boost) headers from /usr/local/include (maybe compiler include path is broken).

Comment: Thank you Pawel for your help! My first header file needs to be #include<boost/array.hpp>.

Comment: The good news is that I could solve this problem by adding '-I /path/to/the/directory/where/boost/headers/are/stored' (in my case: /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.56.0/include).

Answer (score -1):

I asked my professor about this. He gave very detailed explanation, and I think I should share so that everyone can benefit from it:

> Theory:
>   Your compiler needs to know where these files are. You need to find a way to tell it where the files are.

Depending on how you are doing the compiling there will be different solutions.  If you are compiling via the command line, use something like
g++ -I/usr/local/Cellar/boost
The -I stands for "include files".  There is a similar g++ "switch" called -L for libraries when you get to that stage.
There is also a whole series of tools to tell the compiler how to search for include files. The directory /usr/local/include is almost certainly on the list of places for it to look.

If you are using "make" and the associated tools for compiling, you can add the include directories to part of the "Makefile". Again, the details are different for every setting.

Bottom line -- you'll need to learn more about your compiler system. Find manuals and examples for your specific tools and system.  Learn how those tools work and where to specify the boost libraries.  Read the boost manuals and learn where they store files and what all the names are for the different directories where these files are stored.

It's not fun work, but it is worthwhile learning about how all the parts get put together.